# Putty Error while connecting from Local Windows Machine to VM box (Linux) OS

Tags: putty

I am currently working on one task of connecting via Putty (SSH) to a Linux VM box. Putty is installed in local machine with Windows 7 OS.

The connection to VM Linux is required via local loop i.e. 127.0.0.1. I am continuously getting error as "access denied". I have tried following options -

- Disabled SSH GSAAPI authentication (SSH-2 only) on putty connection -->SSH interface
- disabled local windows firewall.

What could be the issue? I am enclosing information about errors as below -

```
login as: dsl dsl@127.0.0.1's 
password: Access denied 
dsl@127.0.0.1's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news is having a password prompt is that your  connection is successful (most likely!) in technical sense.

It would seem that you don't have proper password.

Other possibility is that you didn't specify the correct user you want to login as. When connecting over ssh you specify user as part of the "address" like so:

> rohan@127.0.0.1 would login you as rohan
>
> root@127.0.0.1 would login you as root
>
> 127.0.0.1 will in most cases (I'm not sure how putty does it) use your current username

In the last case while being logged in locally as user `rohan` PuTTy will probably try logging in as `rohan` to the remote system as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88274/discussion-on-answer-by-loa-in-putty-error-while-connecting-from-local-windows).